# Is it possible to get the compression level of a GeoTiff?

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-plugins, geotiff-tiff, compression

When creating a GeoTiff and using Deflate or LZW as compression it is possible to select the level of compression from 1 to 9. Is it possible afterwards to see which level was used?

I have a lot of data which benefits from compression (sometimes easily Gigabytes for just one file) but I'm trying to keep reading quickly as well. Therefore I would like to only use level 1 for my files.

I'm making a plugin in QGIS to quickly analyse all rasters in a project. I'm now showing if a file uses compression, but would like to extend that and show the level of compression as well.

Comment: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153334/how-to-determine-the-compression-level-of-deflate I suppose it is usually not possible.

Comment: You could get the file size on disc and calculate uncompressed file size (rows x columns x bytes_per_pixel x band_count) to show a ratio, although this ignores the overhead of a header (and possible internal pyramids) it's an approximation only.

Answer (score 2):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153334/how-to-determine-the-compression-level-of-deflate. It is not possible to get the compression level from the deflate compressed stream. Same applies to LZW.

It is possible to save the Zlevel that was used during the compression manually with gdal_edit https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html by using the `-mo` option. With JPEG compression GDAL is storing the quality level into the metadata automatically.

```
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=JPEG
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
  JPEGTABLESMODE=1
  JPEG_QUALITY=75
```